# Why the poet said in plural form in Rig Veda VII.91.7?

Tags: rig-veda, vashishta

Rig veda VII.91.7 says :

> अर्व॑न्तो॒ न श्रव॑सो॒ भिक्ष॑माणा इन्द्रवा॒यू सु॑ष्टु॒तिभि॒**र्वसि॑ष्ठाः**
>   । वा॒ज॒यन्त॒: स्वव॑से हुवेम यू॒यं पा॑त स्व॒स्तिभि॒: सदा॑ नः ॥७॥
>
> We, **VASISHTHAS**, (bearing oblations) like horses (bearing burthens),
>   soliciting food, desiring  strength, invoke with praises INDRA and
>   VAYU for (our) sure defence: do you ever cherish us with blessings.

Original mantra and Translation of mantra [is missing](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv07091.htm) in Ralph T.H. Griffith's version.  Hence, I took [mantra from here](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/rigveda/shakala-samhita-2/hindi-rigveda-shakala-samhita-mandal-07-sukta-091/) and [H.H. Wilson's version of translation](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Rigveda_Samhita_Eng_Vol_IV/#book/241).

The rishi is **Vasistha**.

My question is why the poet stated in the mantra **Vasishthas** (plural form), instead of singular form?